# Wordpress SQL dump to restore sample data on new sites

Tags: sql, xml, wordpress, themes

I have set up a wordpress site, installed a theme, imported the sample data xml file, and did a sqldump of the database after completing these steps. I have a script that will automate the creation of the wordpress directory and database for a new site. I would like to add restoring the new database with the dump file. I have been able to do this but the links to wp-admin and wp-login point to the old site's directory instead of the new one. Any idea of why this may be and what can be done to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The sql dump simply had all the data including the absolute links that were generated. So I used perl to search for the strings I needed to update in the sql dump before I put the data into the new database. Thanks.